# raspberry pi python pwm continue after program done

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pwm

I have a robot I am working on and am controlling it with PWM. The way I am controlling it is with a script that sets the PWM and then exits.  I need it to set the PWM and then keep running.  The reason I need it to exit is because I am just calling this script through an ssh connection each time the x and y values change.  Normal digital outputs continue after the program exits but PWM doesn't with the way I have it setup.

Here is my code so far.  It contains a lot of print statements to try to help me figure out what the problem was.

```
#filename: setMotors.py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from sys import argv
from time import sleep

MOTOR_EN_1_PIN = 14
MOTOR_A_1_PIN = 15
MOTOR_B_1_PIN = 18

MOTOR_EN_2_PIN = 23
MOTOR_A_2_PIN = 24
MOTOR_B_2_PIN = 25


def mixXY(x, y):
    """
    mixes x and y from a joystick to values for a 2 motor drive system
    input: x (int or float), y (int or float)
    output: (leftMotor (float), rightMotor (float)) tuple
    """
    leftMotor = y + x
    rightMotor = y - x

    return (leftMotor, rightMotor)

def setMotorPWMS(leftMotor, rightMotor):
    #left motor
    if leftMotor == 0:
        print("left motor 0")
        GPIO.output(MOTOR_EN_1_PIN, 0)
        motor1A.stop()
        motor1B.stop()
    elif leftMotor < 0:
        print("left motor < 0")
        GPIO.output(MOTOR_EN_1_PIN, 1)
        motor1A.stop()
        motor1B.ChangeDutyCycle(abs(leftMotor))
    else:
        print("left motor else")
        GPIO.output(MOTOR_EN_1_PIN, 1)
        motor1A.ChangeDutyCycle(leftMotor)
        motor1B.stop()

    #right motor
    if rightMotor == 0:
        print("right motor 0")
        GPIO.output(MOTOR_EN_2_PIN, 0)
        motor2A.stop()
        motor2B.stop()
    elif rightMotor < 0:
        print("right motor < 0")
        GPIO.output(MOTOR_EN_2_PIN, 1)
        motor2A.stop()
        motor2B.ChangeDutyCycle(abs(rightMotor))
    else:
        print("right motor else")
        GPIO.output(MOTOR_EN_2_PIN, 1)
        motor2A.ChangeDutyCycle(rightMotor)
        motor2B.stop()



GPIO.setwarnings(False)

#setup
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(MOTOR_EN_1_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(MOTOR_A_1_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(MOTOR_B_1_PIN, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.setup(MOTOR_EN_2_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(MOTOR_A_2_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(MOTOR_B_2_PIN, GPIO.OUT)

motor1A = GPIO.PWM(MOTOR_A_1_PIN, 50)
motor1B = GPIO.PWM(MOTOR_B_1_PIN, 50)
motor2A = GPIO.PWM(MOTOR_A_2_PIN, 50)
motor2B = GPIO.PWM(MOTOR_B_2_PIN, 50)
motor1A.start(0)
motor1B.start(0)
motor2A.start(0)
motor2B.start(0)


if len(argv) <= 2:
    print("Need to call with x and y from commandline")
else:
    motorPWM = mixXY(int(argv[1]), int(argv[2]))
    leftMotorPWM = motorPWM[0]
    rightMotorPWM = motorPWM[1]
    print("left motor:",leftMotorPWM)
    print("right motor:", rightMotorPWM)
    setMotorPWMS(leftMotorPWM, rightMotorPWM)
    sleep(5)
    print("done")
```

The way it would be called is with `sudo python setMotors.py x y`.  Is there a way of keeping the PWM going after the program exits or a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The RaspberryPi doesn't support hardware PWM, so it's emulated using a software loop. Basically, it sets the GPIO, sleeps a little, resets the GPIO, sleeps a little and loops. This is done in [a separated thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/code/ci/default/tree/source/soft_pwm.c#l90) which is killed when the program ends.

Thus, you have to find a way to keep your program alive in the background. If you look at the [official example on use of PWM](http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/PWM/), you'll notice the endless loop that keeps the program alive until manually killed.

You should also add something like

```py
try:
    while 1:
        time.sleep(0.5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
p.stop()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

to the end of your program, or something better constructed using the [signal](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/signal.html?highlight=signal#module-signal) module.

Then, leave the process in the background before destroying the console

```
sudo python setMotors.py x y &
```

You could also let your program get [daemonized](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/).